# Printing number of stars with equal spaces to create a V

Tags: c++

I am coding in c++ on a linux system. I am trying to ask the user for an x number of stars they want and when it prints out, if they say for ex 3. I want it to look like this:

```
***      ***
 ***    ***
  ***  ***
   ******
```

So it should print 3 stars on both sides but the 2nd line should start with 1 space and the 3rd line should start with 2 spaces.

Print the first line with (user input) *, followed by 2(user input) spaces, then followed by (user input) *
Print the second line with one space, followed by (user input) *, followed by 2N − 2 spaces, then followed by (user input) *
Continue to print N + 1 lines

I have attached pictures of my current code and the print out. I would like some guidance on how to get it to print all stars and how to do the spacing.

Thank you

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    char star = '*';
    cout << "Please enter a number." << endl;
    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n";
        for (int j = 0; j <= n - i; j++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }

        for(int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
        {
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter a number.
5




    .
   ..
  ...
 ....
.....
```

Comment: "attached pictures of my current code". Please don't do that. Paste the code as formatted text directly into the question. Otherwise others can't easily copy the code to try or reference in a comment/answer. And it is harder to read on mobile devices. Same thing for any text logs.

Comment: What if the user enters an uneven number? Would the right side have 1 extra`*`?

Comment: I worded it wrong. let me reword that. The example I have is of the user entering 3 so it would have 3 stars on each side.

Comment: I clarified what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Just as reference, here is my sample code. Hope it helps.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const char star = '*';

void printSpaces(int line) {
    for(int space = 0; space < line; space++) {
        cout << " ";
    }
}

void printStars(int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << star;
    }
}

void printDoubleSpaces(int n, int line) {
    for(int i = 2*n - 3 - line; i > 0; i--) {
        cout << "  ";
    }
}

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    cout << "Please enter a number." << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for(int line = 0; line < 2*n-2; line++) {
        printSpaces(line);
        printStars(n);
        printDoubleSpaces(n, line);
        printStars(n);
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter a number.
3
***      ***
 ***    ***
  ***  ***
   ******

Please enter a number.
4
****          ****
 ****        ****
  ****      ****
   ****    ****
    ****  ****
     ********

Please enter a number.
5
*****              *****
 *****            *****
  *****          *****
   *****        *****
    *****      *****
     *****    *****
      *****  *****
       **********
```

---

Using a method `strings` instead of @Manny102030 `string(numStars, star)` method.

```
string strings(const int num, const char ch) {
    char result[num+1] = {'\0'};
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        result[i] = ch;
    }
    return result; // covert c-string to string
}
```

---

**Or not using `string` type in C++.**

```
char * strings(const int num, const char ch) {
    char * result = (char *)malloc(num+1); // memory allocate for repeating character
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        result[i] = ch;
    }
    result[num] = '\0';
    return result; 
}

char * stars = strings(numStars, star); // In `main` method, insteading of `string stars = string(numStars, star);`

int spacesBetween = numStars*2; // Space between the stars
for(int i = 0; i < numStars+1; i++)
{
    char * spacesLeft = strings(i, ' ');
    char * spacesMid = strings(spacesBetween, ' ');
    cout << spacesLeft << stars << spacesMid << stars << endl;
    spacesBetween -= 2; // subtract 2 spaces each time
    free(spacesLeft); // free allocated memory for left spaces
    free(spacesMid); // free allocated memory for middle spaces
}
free(stars); // free allocated memory for stars
```

---

New Update：

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void repeatPrint(const int num, const char ch) {
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        cout  << ch;
    }
}

int main() {
    char star = '*';
    char space = ' ';
    int numStars;   // Number of stars on each side

    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> numStars;

    int spacesBetween = numStars*2; // Space between the stars
    for(int i = 0; i < numStars+1; i++)
    {
        repeatPrint(i, space); // Print left spaces
        repeatPrint(numStars, star); // Print stars
        repeatPrint(spacesBetween, space); // Print middle spaces
        repeatPrint(numStars, star); // Print stars
        cout << endl; // Newline
        spacesBetween -= 2; // subtract 2 spaces each time
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I am trying to understand what to do and how to do it. I want to learn, I don't want to just copy.

Comment: @splattered Sorry for my thoughtless. I just want to try to help you understanding via a clear & human-readable code. Do you need me to remove the code or improve my description?

Comment: It's not a problem at all. Again, I really do appreciate you posting the way to do it but I am just trying to learn what each part of the code does that way when I am doing future HW, I actually know what I am doing. I have a professor who doesn't speak English very well and I am having a super hard time understanding him so I am trying to learn on my own and learn as much as possible from him. If you don't mind, the code that Manny wrote seems familiar to me because of the functions he/she has used. Yours has some things I haven't seen before. Would you help me undertheir their code instead?

Comment: @splattered OK. Do you want to use the other way instead of the `string(numStars, star)` method? Or instead of the `string` type in C++? I post another answer for insteading of `string(numStars, star)` method. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: We haven't done strings yet so I wanted to do it without that function.

Comment: @splattered Sure. You can try my function which be bold in my post. Or refer to my new update.

Comment: The declaration `char result[num+1];` is not valid in standard C++. It is valid in C: a feature called Variable Length Array, a VLA, that was introduced in C99. In C++ you can use a `std::vector` or a `std::string` (but you really don't need that variable).

Comment: All of the above codes were compiled successfully via g++ (gcc 6.2.0 version)on Debian Linux, and work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char star = '*';
    char space = ' ';
    int numStars;   // Number of stars on each side

    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> numStars;

    string stars = string(numStars, star); // Example, if numStars were 3, it would become '***'

    int spacesBetween = numStars*2; // Space between the stars
    for(int i = 0; i < numStars+1; i++)
    {
        cout << string(i, ' ') << stars << string(spacesBetween, ' ') << stars << endl;
        spacesBetween -= 2; // subtract 2 spaces each time
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Without the string() function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char star = '*';
    char space = ' ';
    int numStars;   // Number of stars on each side

    cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    cin >> numStars;

    // I commented this out to show how you can do it without string()
    //string stars = string(numStars, star);
    string stars = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < numStars; i++)
    {
        stars += star; // stars += '*'
    }

    int spacesBetween = numStars*2; // Number of spaces between the stars
    string spaces = ""; // Spaces between the stars
    for(int i = 0; i < numStars+1; i++)
    {
        spaces = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < spacesBetween; i++)
        {
            spaces += ' ';
        }
        cout << string(i, ' ') << stars << spaces << stars << endl;
        spacesBetween -= 2; // subtract 2 spaces each time
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me more about the string stars line? Is there a way to do it without the string stars?

Comment: the string() function that I used is pretty simple. string(number, character) basically outputs a string made up of a number of characters. string(4, '+') would return "++++" (4 plus signs), string(3, 'a') would return "aaa" (3 'a's), string(5, '*') would return "*****" (5 stars), etc. And yes you can do it without it, I changed my answer to include a way without using the string stars line.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like some guidance on how to get it to print all stars and how
>   to do the spacing.

I think Peter Pan's answer is quite readable.

> but I am trying to understand what to do and how to do it. I want to
>   learn, I don't want to just copy.

You have tagged this post as C++, below I have provide a possible C++ approach.

I used recursion (simply to discourage you from copying, questions are welcome).  Otherwise, my version (which I consider more C++'ish) is quite similar to the other answers.

---

What to do:

a) capture your expected output (for 3), and count each subset of characters.  Perhaps write the output V on a grid.

Repeat for at least one other N.  This will help you identify the lengths of the various sections  (see step c, below), and the code provided (both mine and others) shows some possible implementations, how the grid size affects the calculations.

b) partition the write of a "star V" problem into line by line actions.

I have not labeled the lines  The recursion builds each line, one after the other... perhaps the only label for this idea is 0..N.  Perhaps a "for-loop"?

c) decide how to produce each line.

I have dreamed up labels for each of the 4 sections of each line,

- leftMargin - spaces with an indent (to center the lines)
- stars - each line needs the N numbers (twice)
- spaces - for clearing the area between the uprights (like in football?)

c) for each line section, I create methods to produce the string desired.
(I called them leftMargin, stars, spaces ... ).

I used std::stringstream methods (from #include sstream" and iomanip methods to generate the strings (rather than using my own for loops).

d) The recursion method V1r uses a parameter identifying termination and used in line creation.  V1r recurses prior to cout'ing the lines.

e) The recursion method inverted_V1r works much the same way.  However, it recurses after cout'ing the lines.

---

Read each note above, and compare to the code, and give it a try.

I recommend you write a simple for loop, and tackle only V1 first.  Good luck.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
class T452_t
{
private:
   int N;   

public:
   T452_t(int argc, char* argv[])  // ctor
      {
         switch (argc)
         {
         case 2: { N = std::stoi(argv[1]); } break;

         default: {
            std::cerr << " require one number, with value > 2" << std::endl;
            exit(-1);
         } break;
         }
      }

   // using stringstream and iomanip
   std::string leftMargin(int lvl) {
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(2+(N-lvl)) << " ";
      return (ss.str());      // ----------^^^^^^^^---computed indent
   }

   std::string stars() {
      std::stringstream ss;
      ss << std::setfill('*') << std::setw(N) << "*";
      return (ss.str());      // ----------^--- quantity
   }

   std::string spaces(int lvl) {
      std::stringstream ss;
      if (0 != lvl)    // no spaces at lvl 0
         ss << std::setfill(' ') << std::setw(lvl*2) << " ";
      return (ss.str());         // ----------^^^^^--- quantity
   }


   // using recursion
   void V1r(int lvl)
      {
         if(lvl > N) return; // recursion termination clause

         V1r(lvl+1);

         std::cout << leftMargin(lvl)
                   << stars() << spaces(lvl) << stars()
                   << std::endl;
      }


   // recursion
   void inverted_V1r(int lvl) // upside down V1r
      {
         if(lvl > N) return; // recursion termination clause

         std::cout << leftMargin(lvl)
                   << stars() << spaces(lvl) << stars()
                   << std::endl;
         inverted_V1r(lvl+1);               // tail recursion possible
      }


   int exec()
      {
         if (N < 2) { std::cerr << " value < 2 is too small" << std::endl; exit(-2); }
         std::cout << std::endl;

         V1r(0);

         std::cout << "\n"<< std::endl;
         inverted_V1r(0);

         std::cout << std::endl;
         return(0);
      }
}; // class T452_t

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
   std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point  m_start_us =
      std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

   int retVal = -1;
   {
      T452_t  t452 (argc, argv);
      retVal = t452.exec();
   }

   std::chrono::microseconds  chrono_duration_us =
      std::chrono::duration_cast <std::chrono::microseconds>
      (std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - m_start_us);

   std::cout << chrono_duration_us.count() << " us" << std::endl;
   return(retVal);
}
```

---

Example output (3):

```
real    0m1.150s
user    0m1.004s
sys 0m0.104s

  ***      ***
   ***    ***
    ***  ***
     ******


     ******
    ***  ***
   ***    ***
  ***      ***

204 us
```

Example output: (7)

```
  *******              *******
   *******            *******
    *******          *******
     *******        *******
      *******      *******
       *******    *******
        *******  *******
         **************


         **************
        *******  *******
       *******    *******
      *******      *******
     *******        *******
    *******          *******
   *******            *******
  *******              *******

286 us
```